# Weird scala errors. found: scala.Double required Double

Tags: scala, functional-programming, tree

I have a tree that stores list of elements in nodes. 
I need to write a function that takes such tree and returns tree that has sum of  elements in nodes.

I thought that it was an easy task but some errors have occurred:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0e0O.png)

Here is what IntelliJ shows:

[code with compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkHxB.png)

And finally here is my code:

```
sealed trait tree[+A]
case object Empty extends tree[Nothing]
case class Node[A](element:A,left:tree[A],right:tree[A]) extends tree[A]

val tr=Node(List(1,2,3),Node(List(3,4,5),Empty,Node(List(2,4,5),Empty,Empty)),Node(List(6,7,8),Empty,Empty))

def transformTree[Double](t:tree[List[Double]]):tree[Double]={
t match{
case Empty => Empty
case Node(l,left,right)=>Node[Double](l.foldLeft(0)((a:Double,b:Double)=>(a+b)),transformTree(left),transformTree(right))
}
}
   transformTree(tr)
```

I have no idea why it is expecting string there so please explain this to me if you can :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Class names should start with uppercase.
2. `0` is a 32-bit integer, you want `0d` for 64-bit `Double`s.
3. You want to define `transformTree` for `Double`, not for an arbitrary type bound to type variable called `Double`. Currently, your function signature is equivalent to `def transformTree[X](t: Tree[List[X]]): Tree[X]`, and almost nothing is known about `X` except that it is subtype of `Any`, and thus has a `+` operation for concatenating its string representation with other strings.
4. Your `tr` should be `Tree[Double]`, not `Tree[Int]`.
5. There is `sum`, no need to `fold` anything. Even if you wanted to `foldLeft`, it should have been something like `l.foldLeft(0d)(_ + _)`.

This compiles:

```
sealed trait Tree[+A]
case object Empty extends Tree[Nothing]
case class Node[A](element:A,left:Tree[A],right:Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]

val tr = Node(List(1d,2d,3d),Node(List(3d,4d,5d),Empty,Node(List(2d,4d,5d),Empty,Empty)),Node(List(6d,7d,8d),Empty,Empty))

def transformTree(t: Tree[List[Double]]): Tree[Double] = {
  t match{
    case Empty => Empty
    case Node(l, left, right) => 
      Node[Double](l.sum, transformTree(left), transformTree(right))
  }
}
transformTree(tr)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well... the thing is when you define a `def` like following,

```
def abc[A](a: A) = ??
```

This `A` here is a generic type parameter and this type parameter `A` takes highest precedence in type resolution inside the `def` scope. So, any other type `A` will not be recognised as `A` in this scope.

In simpler terms, if you do something like

```
def abc[Double](a: Double) = a
```

This `Double` here is not actual `Double` which you know, but is a type parameter which is open for the user of this `def`.

And the above line is equivalent to,

```
def abc[A](a: A) = a
// Or
def abc[B](b: B) = b
```

This means that inside the scope of your `def transformTree[Double]` `def`, these `Double` are not actual `Double` but a variable type which will be decided at when the function is actually used.

And since you are using that `a + b` `fold` starting with `0`, it means that your `transform` is pretty much type fixed. And if you want to implement it for `Double`,

```
sealed trait Tree[+A]
case object Empty extends Tree[Nothing]
case class Node[A](element: A, left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]

val tr = Node(
  List(1d, 2d, 3d),
  Node(
    List(3d, 4d, 5d),
    Empty,
    Node(
      List(2d, 4d, 5d),
      Empty,
      Empty
    )
  ),
  Node(
    List(6d, 7d, 8d),
    Empty,
    Empty
  )
)

def transformTree(t: Tree[List[Double]]): Tree[Double] = {
  t match {
    case Empty => Empty
    case Node(l, left, right) => Node(
      l.foldLeft(0d)((acc: Double, elem: Double) => (acc + elem)),
      transformTree(left),
      transformTree(right)
    )
  }
}

transformTree(tr)
```